# i am creating 19 different macro variables from one variable "name" and last macro variable is resolving in the if condition (requirement)

Tags: sas, macros

```
options mprint mlogic symbolgen ;

%macro origin ;
data check ;
 set sashelp.class ;
  call symputx("local"||strip(put(_n_,best.)), name) ;
  run ; 
  
  %let cnt = &sysnobs. ;
  
  data check_one (keep = name macro_resolve );
   set check ;
   %do i= 1 %to &cnt. ;
    if age = 16 then do ;
     macro_resolve = symget("local&i.");
    end; 
   %end ;
   %symdel local&i. ;
run;

%mend origin ;

%origin ;
```

The first step in the macro creates 19 macro variables (19 observations in "NAME" varaible)
In second step, i want to use the particular macro variable created by that observation for the condition satisfied.

Comment: As noted by @Richard below, why are you doing this?  Note that using macro variables as a 'pass through' to temporarily store values that are read from a SAS dataset before writing them to another SAS dataset is rarely (never?) a good idea.  You lose precision, and introduce complexity.  It's better to keep the values in the data, and combine with SQL join, merge, or whatever logic.

Answer (score 1):

- Why are you doing this?
- Why are you resolving only when age=16 ?
- The first DATA step should be `_null_`
- Why are you doing `SYMDEL`, local symbols go away when the macro completes

You should use the 'L' option in `SYMPUTX` to force local symbol creation and not accidentally overwrite global symbols of the same name.

When you `SYMGET` you are not resolving, you are getting the macro variable value.

```
%macro foo;
  %* create a symbol named NAME# from each row in the table ;
  data _null_ ;
    set sashelp.class;
    call symputx (cats('name',_n_),name, 'L');
  run;
  %* What name do those 16 year olds get? ;
  data compare;
    set sashelp.class;
    if age = 16 then do;
      mvar = cats('name',_n_);
      mval = symget(mvar);
    end;
    %* No need for SYMDEL;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%do` loop within the second data step is not relevant as it overlaps with the data step loop. A possible problem with this is the reliance on the position of the variable. It's more useful to use a primary key to index the variables.

This works for me:

```
options mprint mlogic symbolgen;

%macro origin ;
data check ;
 set sashelp.class ;
  call symputx("local"||strip(put(_n_,best.)), name) ;
  run ; 
  
  %let cnt = &sysnobs. ;

  
  data check_one (keep = name age macro_resolve );
   set check ;

    if age = 16 then do;
     macro_resolve = symget(catt("local", put(_n_, 8. -l)));
    end; 


run;


%mend origin ;
%origin ;
```